# Construct shortest valid css selector using BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am using the following function construct a css selector using BS4:

```
def nth_of_type(elem):
    count, curr = 0, 0
    for i, e in enumerate(elem.find_parent().find_all(recursive=False), 1):
        if e.name == elem.name:
            count += 1
        if e == elem:
            curr = i
    return '' if count == 1 else ':nth-child({})'.format(curr)

def getCssPath(elem):
    rv = [elem.name + nth_of_type(elem)]
    while True:
        elem = elem.find_parent()
        if not elem or elem.name == '[document]':
            return '>'.join(rv[::-1])
        rv.append(elem.name + nth_of_type(elem))
```

So if I scrape a page using:

```
    page_r = requests.get('<my url>')
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_r.content, 'html.parser')
    elements = page_soup.find_all('a')
    print(getCssPath(elements[0])
    # html>body>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(6)>div>div>main>article>div>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>div>div>div>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(1)>div>div>div>div>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(2)>div>div:nth-child(4)>a`
```

But this is very long so I want to get the shortest CSS selector. Similar to the one you can get when you right click on the element in chrome and do `Copy > Selector`. This can involve classes and ids etc.

Is there any BS4 function already to get that or how should this function be modified to get that?

Comment: you could try to use `elem.attrs.get('class')` and `elem.attrs.get('id')` but it still need code which could check if selector gets only one item. I think I didn't show function for this in [BeautifulSoup doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) so you will have to write own.